# How to make all \parbox with same height

Tags: lengths, size, parbox

Running the following MWE will get an ugly typeset which I think is for the reason of different heights of all thees`\parbox`s.

My question is: As the contents of all `\parbox` cannot be foreseen, how to make all these `\parbox` in the same line have the same height(the height of the tallest box, for example) without extra or less vertical space.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{%
  \colorbox{yellow!30}{\fbox{\parbox[c]{.5in}{M}}}
  \colorbox{yellow!30}{\fbox{\parbox[c]{1in}{M\\M}}}
  \colorbox{yellow!30}{\fbox{\parbox[c]{1.5in}{M\\M\\M}}}
  \colorbox{yellow!30}{\fbox{\parbox[c]{2in}{M\\M\\M}}}% 
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: check the tcolorbox package. It has code for raster layouts.

Comment: Thank you @Ulrike Fischer. `tcolorbox` is too heavy for simple items.

Comment: `\parbox` has other optional arguments, including height: `\parbox[c][3\baselineskip][c]{0.5in}{M}`  The first [c] places the baseline, the second [c] centers the text inside the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the height of the tallest box can be tricky.  One solution is to put all of the boxes inside a savebox.  Note that the total height equals the height (above the baseline) plus the depth (below the baseline).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength{\maxheight}

\begin{document}
\sbox0{\parbox[c]{.5in}{M}\parbox[c]{1in}{M\\M}\parbox[c]{1.5in}{M\\M\\M}}%
\setlength{\maxheight}{\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0}%
\fboxsep=0pt
\noindent\fbox{%
  \colorbox{yellow!30}{\fbox{\parbox[c][\maxheight][c]{.5in}{M}}}
  \colorbox{yellow!30}{\fbox{\parbox[c][\maxheight][c]{1in}{M\\M}}}
  \colorbox{yellow!30}{\fbox{\parbox[c][\maxheight][c]{1.5in}{M\\M\\M}}}
  \colorbox{yellow!30}{\fbox{\parbox[c][\maxheight][c]{2in}{M\\M\\M}}}% 
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I like the idea "to put all of the boxes inside a savebox". Still, if the number of `\parbox` in the same line is not contant, how to append a new \parbox to `\sbox0`? I mean, when writing a new `\parbox`, it is appended to `\sbox0` thant is to say, if there ia such a way like `\append\sbox0{...}?

Comment: You can use `\sbox0{\usebox0\parbox{...}}` although I usually switch boxes each time on general principles.  Also, I usually only use boxes 0-9 inside groups so that they are only defined locally, but didn't want to complicate the code.  You can also created named saveboxes using `\newsavebox{\foo}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l |l |l |l |}\hline
\rowcolor{yellow}
 \parbox{.5in}{M} &
 \parbox{1in}{M\\M} &
 \parbox{1.5in}{M\\M\\M} &
 \parbox{2in}{M\\M\\M} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1.Many thanks. And any solution without a special package to solove my question?

Comment: If you want colors you need a color package. I do not use any other "special" package!!